# SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns

Tags: spservices, dropdown, cascading

I need help with SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns. I need to create 3 level cascade dropdown fields. But I have some problems with it, so I need help.

Here are my lists. 
First lists is PrimaryDomains,

[image]

Next list is SecondaryDomains

[image]

Third one is SubDomains:
[image]

And main list is IT.
First two fields are working, but on third field it doesn't. Here is picture and error on custom form.
[image]

Here is my code from New custom form from SharePoint Designer

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.7.1a/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {
 $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
 relationshipList: "SecondaryDomains",
 relationshipListParentColumn: "PrimaryDomain",
 relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
 relationshipListSortColumn: "Title",
 parentColumn: "Primary_Domain",
 childColumn: "Secondary_Domain",
 debug: true
 });

$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
 relationshipList: "SubDomains",
 relationshipListParentColumn: "SecondaryDomain",
 relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
 parentColumn: "Secondary_Domain",
 childColumn: "Sub_Domain ",
 debug: true
  });
});
</script>
```

Also maybe I need to say that I will have more than 20 items in list SubDomains.

Thanks!

Comment: Please check the the Spelling of SecondaryDomain, in your screen shot it Shows inside SubDomains list ,for column  SecondaryDomian and in your script it shows   relationshipListParentColumn: "SecondaryDomain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made some spelling mistakes,like in your screen shot 
In **SubDomains** list display name for column **SecondaryDomian**
In your script it shows **SecondaryDomain**, change column value use bwlow script

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"   
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.7.1a/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
relationshipList: "SecondaryDomains",
relationshipListParentColumn: "PrimaryDomain",
relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
relationshipListSortColumn: "Title",
parentColumn: "Primary_Domain",
childColumn: "Secondary_Domain",
debug: true
});

$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
relationshipList: "SubDomains",
relationshipListParentColumn: "SecondaryDomian",
relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
parentColumn: "Secondary_Domain",
childColumn: "Sub_Domain ",
debug: true
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I correct that spelling mistake, but still the same error

Comment: that means there is something misplaced in your sript. Once again go through your script, find out is their ant spelling mistake or check you have place all columns name right

Comment: I did it, I made a list again and now everything is working, thanks a lot

Comment: great efforts ,Sounds good. finally you made it.

Answer (score 2):

You have made some spelling mistakes. In the Scripts you're using

```
relationshipListParentColumn: "SecondaryDomian",
```

but your ParentColumns exact name is "**SecondaryDomian**".

Use the scripts as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
 relationshipList: "SecondaryDomains",
 relationshipListParentColumn: "PrimaryDomain",
 relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
 relationshipListSortColumn: "Title",
 parentColumn: "Primary_Domain",
 childColumn: "Secondary_Domain",
 debug: true
 });

$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
 relationshipList: "SubDomains",
 relationshipListParentColumn: "SecondaryDomian",
 relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
 parentColumn: "Secondary_Domain",
 childColumn: "Sub_Domain ",
 debug: true
  });
});
```

Change the script not the list field name.

Comment: I did it, I made a list again and now everything is working, thanks a lot

Comment: Great. Please mark it answered if it helped.